# Error on applying linq to List

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I am trying to create a sublist from a larger list using `linq`

```
List<ScenarioDetailModel> chartScenarioDetailsList = new List<ScenarioDetailModel>();

List<ScenarioDetailModel> subList = new List<ScenarioDetailModel>();
subList = chartScenarioDetailsList.Where(s => s.Code == "C3");
```

Both `chartScenarioDetailsList` and `subList` are of the same type but the compiler complains about type conversions and won't compile, the error is as follows:

> Error  190 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

However, it compiles when I change the sublist's type from `List` to `IEnumerable`:

```
IEnumerable<ScenarioDetailModel> subList = new List<ScenarioDetailModel>();
subList = chartScenarioDetailsList.Where(s => s.Code == "C3");
```

My question is: why does this happen?

Comment: Try adding `.ToList()` at the end of the where statement. As it returns an enumerable, not a list

Comment: Another question is: do you really need a list or you can work with an enumerable? apply ToList() means creating a new object and referring the elements from the other object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where() does return an IEnumerable, not a List.

Try `subList = chartScenarioDetailsList.Where(s => s.Code == "C3").ToList();`

Also, you should assign subList directly with

`chartScenarioDetailsList.Where(s => s.Code == "C3").ToList();`

and not with new, since by doing so you're losing the reference created by your call to new.

Answer (score 0):

`var subList = chartScenarioDetailsList.FindAll(s => s.Code == "C3");`

But you really should embrace the `IEnumerable` concept, as suggested by others in comments and answers:

```
// I temporarily need a local sub-list to do something
// Approach 1 (older list approach)

{ // scope of subList
    var subList = chartScenarioDetailsList.FindAll(s => s.Code == "C3");
    foreach (var detail in subList)
    { /* do a thing with detail */ }
} // end of scope

// Approach 2 (enumerable approach)

foreach (var detail in chartScenarioDetailsList.Where(s => s.Code == "C3"))
{ /* do a thing with detail */ }
```

If your use of the sub-list is immediate and temporary, you can skip it altogether, and just iterate over the `Where` result.